# How can I create a HTTP POST request with Qt 4.6.1?

Tags: c++, http, qt4

How can I create a HTTP POST request with some URL encoded parameters using Qt 4.6.1?

I figured out that I can create a QNetworkRequest, set all the parameters there and send it via QNetworkAccessManagers post method. But how can I add some URL-encoded parameters to the request?

In the end I want to access the [Eve API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_Online#Third-party_applications_and_the_Eve_API_Project) using Qt/C++. A Python example can be found here:
http://www.eveonline.com/api/doc/example-python.asp

---

I managed it using something like (still to be refactored and formed into something useful):

```
QNetworkReply *requestApi(QNetworkAccessManager &nwam)
{

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://api.eve-online.com/account/Characters.xml.aspx"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QByteArray data;
    QUrl params;

    params.addQueryItem("userid","user");
    params.addQueryItem("apiKey","key");
    data.append(params.toString());
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkReply *reply = nwam.post(request,data);
    return reply;
}
```

Comment: [QUrl::addEncodedQueryItem()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qurl.html#addEncodedQueryItem) ? I'm using Qt myself, but haven't been using the HTTP parts that much... yet.

Comment: For your use case the QNetworkAccessManager seems like overkill. Why not just use libcurl?

Answer (score 11):

Your solution is almost right. But one should use:

```
data = params.encodedQuery();
```

instead of

```
data.append(params.toString());
data.remove(0,1);
```

to handle UTF8 strings properly.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry that I only find your post this late.
However, I'll still try to help, in case anyone else is searching for the answer.

By accident, I'm also working on an EVE API application, and I also tried the same way. Unfortunately, `QNetworkManager` doesn't work that way, because it posts the request asynchronously. You have to connect a slot to its `finished(QNetworkReply*)` signal.

I do it by making a request with a separate class called `EveConnector`, processing the reply in the slot connected to the `QNetworkManager`'s `finished` signal, and then calling back the requesting object through the connector class's own signals.

I would happily share the code, if you ask.