# How to use post() in qt?

Tags: qt, post

This is my program. In this program I want to send request to a website (for example: http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html)
I want to show the html code that return me in plain text box.

```
QUrl url("http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html")
```

I want to give html code in "thisfile"

```
file.setFileName("thisfile.html");

if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    std::cerr << "Error: Cannot write file "
    << qPrintable(file.fileName()) << ": "
    << qPrintable(file.errorString()) << std::endl

    return false;
}

http.setHost(url.host(),80);
http.post(url.toString(),"term=yyyy&loc=en_us&siteSection=products%3Amuse",&file);
```

This code doesn't work correctly and when I show the file give me false html code. What do I have to do?

Comment: What is the scope of `file` instance? Is it local to that block?

Answer (score 1):

Use `http.get()` instead of `http.post()` as `POST` method requires to set other `Headers` used by server.

`QHttp::get()` method is **asynchronous** too.

As your case is simple enough just to retrieve `HTML` response, you should go for `HTTP GET` IMHO. [See difference between `GET` and `POST` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080863/what-is-the-difference-between-a-http-get-and-http-post-and-what-is-http-post-se).

And if you have to use `HTTP POST` only, then [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214595/how-can-i-create-a-http-post-request-with-qt-4-6-1).

Comment: thanks for your replay i do this befor : Replace url.toString() to url.path() in http.post() line buth not use full

Comment: i have to use post in my project

Comment: I have updated my answer. It returns correct html for `http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 QNetworkRequest request;
 request.setUrl(QUrl("thisfile.html"));

 QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, "term=yyyy&loc=en_us&siteSection=products%3Amuse");
 connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
```

Look at QNetworkAccessManager at [qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)

You have to read information and save it to file at `readyRead` function

Comment: thanks for your replay but i have a question: where i must be set the address of file(&file) that for savig  html cod that post giv it to me?

Comment: hi thehorse please help me and replay to me

Comment: at my example, you have to implement file operations at slot "slotReadyRead".