# beego can't receive the correct http POST from QT

Tags: php, html, qt, beego

The post Which I Use QT's QNetworkAccessManager received by beego doesn't have Form fields. but its content-length is not empty.

like this:

> {Method:POST URL://search Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1
>   Header:map[Content-Type:[multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------2018-05-11 09:42:02]
>   Content-Length:[949776] Connection:[Keep-Alive] Accept-Encoding:[gzip,
>   deflate] Accept-Language:[zh-CN,en,*] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0]]
>   Body:0xc04214ae80 GetBody: ContentLength:949776
>   TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:#.#.#.#:# Form:map[]
>   PostForm:map[] MultipartForm: Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr::#.#.#.#:#
>   RequestURI://search TLS: Cancel: Response:
>   ctx:0xc04214aec0}

But when I post this to PHP, $_POST has the fileds

Comment: How you construct and send  POST ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use post() in qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992618/how-to-use-post-in-qt)

Comment: I find out why it happened. There was a Blank in my boundary. Remove it, everything goes well. Thank you guys